# List object is not callable

Tags: python-3.x, scikit-learn

```
tfidf_matrix = tfidf_vectorizer.fit_transform(checkList)
```

`checkList` is a list of text items

There is an error occuring after I try to execute this line.

```
TypeError: 'list' object is not callable
```

Can anyone explain?

Comment: Could you provide the entire error message please?

Answer (score 1):

Mostly that kind of errors have something to do with the variable declaration. 
Might be something else tho, if you could post the code, it'll be helpful to be specific
However if declaration is the case, procedure behind it is that "checklist" variable is not defined correctly or there is a problem with that. So when you call that variable you expected to have a list, but instead you are having a incomplete or problematic list object.

So double check the code syntax, specially if the list has been passed. even the missing bracket or sometimes having brackets (if you are calling from a library) could cause problems to define variable

Answer (score 1):

My guess is that you may not have defined the tfidf vectorizer properly. Try this!

```
from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import TfidfVectorizer

tfidf_vectorizer = TfidfVectorizer()
tfidf_matrix = tfidf_vectorizer.fit_transform(checkList)
```